# Java/Android Bouncy castle ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle, classnotfoundexception

I am writing an application for the Android platform which makes use of cryptography. It's a secure chat, client->server->client with diffie hellman keys.
Clients are android phones and the server is running on my PC.
I am trying to send the public key via sockets but i am getting this error:

```
Server Up and Running
Bouncy Castle provider is available
Aug 21, 2016 4:47:03 PM Connection run
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dh.BCDHPublicKey
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at Connection.run(Connection.java:124)
```

As you can see bouncy castle provider is available.
Here is my code with the problem:

Server:

```
if (Security.getProvider("BC") == null){
      System.out.println("Bouncy Castle provider is NOT available");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Bouncy Castle provider is available");
    }

try {
     pubkey = (PublicKey) instream.readObject();
}catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Android:

```
PublicKey pubkey;
kp23 = genDHKeyPair();
pubkey= kp23.getPublic();
//System.out.println(pubkey);
outstream.writeObject(pubkey);
outstream.flush();
```

Comment: The android VM is *not* a a Java VM. You can't deserialize objects between the two, they are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The version of BouncyCastle available on android os is [very limited](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3280) and apparently it does't include the `com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dh.BCDHPublicKey`.

If you want full BouncyCastle functionality, you need to include the version that was repackaged with Android in mind, which is the [SpongyCastle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle) cryptography provider.

Follow [this link](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) for more explanations.

Comment: I add the Spongy Castle but I still had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` is thrown because the package `com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dh.BCDHPublicKey` is not available in the java version of BouncyCastle which includes the equivalent `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dh.BCDHPublicKey`.

I suggest you to create a new class with the following properties on **both** Server and Client applications.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PublicKeyProperties implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public byte[] Encoded;
    public String Format;
    public String Algorithm;
}
```

**Client side**

Pass the `PublicKey`'s corresponding properties to a new instance of `PublicKeyProperties` class, serialize it and send it to the server.

```
PublicKeyProperties prop = new PublicKeyProperties();
prop.Format = pubkey.getFormat();
prop.Algorithm = pubkey.getAlgorithm();
prop.Encoded = pubkey.getEncoded();
outstream.writeObject(prop);
```

**Server side**

Deserialize it and create a new `PublicKey` instance as follows.

```
PublicKeyProperties prop = (PublicKeyProperties) instream.readObject();

pubkey = new PublicKey() {

                 @Override
                 public String getAlgorithm() {
                    return prop.Algorithm;
                 }

                 @Override
                 public String getFormat() {
                    return prop.Format;
                 }

                 @Override
                 public byte[] getEncoded() {
                    return prop.Encoded;
                 }
            };
```

Hope that helps.